# lemma on functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

searching for exercises on continuous function I found one, which I rewrote here :

**Def** : let $[a;b]$ be a set on which a continuous real function $f$ is defined.Let $[A;B]$ be a subset of $[a;b]$
we say that [A;B] is $f$-dominating over $[a;b]$if

$\forall x \in [a;b], \exists y \in [A;B]$ st. $f(y)\geq f(x)$ (1)

**Lemma :**
let $C \in [A;B]$ then either $[A;C]$ is $f$-dominating over $[a;b]$ or$[C;B]$ is.

**Exercise :** Prove this lema without using the fact that continuous functions on a close interval are bounded. (ie. without the extreme value theorem)

I started the proof this way

If $[A;C]$ is $f$-dominating then proof is done.

Let's then consider $[A;C]$ is not $f$-dominating. This translates to
$$\exists x \in [a;b]\text{ st. } \forall y \in [A;C],  f(x)>f(y)$$
But then from $(1)$

...

Thus $[B;C]$ is $f$-dominating.

Can anyone help me filling the dots ?

PS : $f$ is continuous of course ! added to the post

Comment: are you assuming that $f$ is continuous ?

Comment: yes, Thank you!

Comment: So if I understand the problem correctly, $[A;B]$ is assumed to be $f$-dominating to start with, right? And then we must show that either $[A;C]$ or $[B;C]$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Lemma** Let $f$ be a (continuous) function defined on $[a;b]$. Let $[A;B]$ be $f$-dominating over $[a;b]$, and let $C\in[A;B]$ be given. Then either $[A;C]$ or $[C;B]$ is $f$-dominating over $[a;b]$.

---

The proof starts off as you stated:

If $[A;C]$ is $f$-dominating, the proof is done.

---

Now set $x'\in[a;b]$ such that
$$
f(x')>f(y)
$$
for all $y\in[A;C]$. Hence $M=f(x')$ is an upper bound on $f([A;C])$. But at the same time there exists $y'\in[A;B]$ such that
$$
f(y')\geq f(x')=M
$$
Now since $y'\in[A;B]$ but $y'\notin[A;C]$ this implies $y'\in[C;B]$.

(actually it is in (C;B] so it is in [C;B] as well)

---

Now let any $x\in[a;b]$ be given:

- If $f(x)\leq M$ we have $f(y')\geq f(x)$ where $y'\in[C;B]$.
- If $f(x)>M$ we cannot find a dominating $f(y)$ over $[A;C]$ and resort to the same argument as for $x',y'$ to show that there exists $y\in[C;B]$ such that $f(y)\geq f(x)$.

Thus $[C;B]$ is $f$-dominating over $[a;b]$.

Comment: Actually continuity is not needed in your argument. However if we assume continuity this lemma can be used to give a different proof of the fact that any continuous function on a closed interval attains a maximum.

Comment: @harmonicuser: Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: There is no need for continuity in the proof after asking to the author, The lemma is use to prove the extreme value theorem. I was confused by reading your message because in french upper bound means $\sup$.

Comment: @TomDomenge: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: @String please remove the first (this comes from the fact on the proposed edit, I did a wrong paste, thanks)